# Trouble loading external html file with jQuery .load

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to dynamically load content on a simple page. I want to fade in the content.html I'm trying to link, then any other link I click will load a div from the content.html and fade in. I think I do this with `.load("html.html #section");` but this is as far as I've gotten.

This is in my `<head>`

```
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // $(".content").load("content.html");
        // $(".content").fadeIn(800);
        $(".menu ul li a").click(function(){
            $(".content").load("content.html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

body page with the content div im trying to load into

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="gradient">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="nav">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <strong>
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Sam Jarvis logo"/>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#work">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#clients">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footerText">    
            <div class="footerCopyright">
                <p>© 2013 Sam Jarvis | Design and Development. All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#work">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#clients">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
```

console says

```
OPTIONS file://localhost/Users/eveo/Projects/Sites/Sam/content.html Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery.min.js:6
send jquery.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:6
x.fn.load jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous function) index.html:21
x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
v.handle jquery.min.js:5
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Users/eveo/Projects/Sites/Sam/content.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. index.html:1
```

Comment: Whats your console say?

Comment: Should work, what is issue in that?

Comment: No idea, posted the console log but I'm still not sure :(

Comment: Are you getting a page refresh?

Comment: You appear to be requesting from `file://localhost` rather than `http://localhost`. Work from a webserver and you won't have this problem. XAMP, WAMP, etc.

Comment: Nope. Not getting anything, you can clone it and test yourself here: https://github.com/eveo/Sam

Comment: What do you mean? I just opened the index.html file from my HD and it loads as `file://localhost/Users/eveo/Projects/Sites/Sam/index.html#home`

edit: Okay I see what you mean thanks.

Comment: Correct, that's not a webserver, that's your filesystem. you can't perform ajax requests to your filesystem without first opening your browser with reduced security settings. Suggested fix is still *install a webserver*

Comment: Yep, the browser sees it as two different domains, and invokes a COR policy to prevent jQuery from loading content from another "domain"

Comment: What do you recommend as an extremely light weight webserver? I don't want all of these programs running all the time for the smallest of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".menu ul li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".content").load("content.html",function() {
                $(".content").fadeIn(800);
            });
      });
});
```

Always use the `preventDefault()` if you are dynamically loading from a link to prevent any possible page refreshes. Also, you can use the `.load()` callback to `.fadeIn()` the content. Of course, this is all for naught if you're trying to load **HTML** content from your filesystem.

Comment: Hey thanks for editing the response, I would have taken a much more pioneered approach.